# How to display a fragment without replacing the content in the other fragment android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have this fragment call it `fragmentControl`, I also have this other fragment called `fragmentHandle` FragmentHandle is inform of a picture in picture mode, meaning it's a small screen on the left corner. I want when I click `fragmentHandle` , I display `fragmentControl` details without replacing whats shown on `fragmentHandle`. FragmentControl has a motion layout and I am wondering what would be the best steps to show this fragment as in have it fade in and fade out to the right corner.

I think creating a duplicate `motionLayout` does not make sense. I appreciate any thoughts and assistance.

Comment: where is your codes please?

Comment: It's alot of code, so can't paste it all here.

Comment: You don't need to paste all of the code, just the relevant to reproduce the issue